# HTML: copy code from template

Tags: html, css, copy

i am responsible for the webpage of a group, but am not really in expert in html. I know a lot of the basics, though.

So all the pages have a css navigation bar. 
The content of this is copied and pasted into all html files, since they all contain the bar.

I need to do some changes to the text and redirecting of parts of the bar and would like to know, if there is an easier way then editing it for one html-page and then copy+paste it to other html files?

Like setting up one (html) file with only the contents of this bar and then refering it from all the different html pages?
With this solution, in the future I would only have to change this one particular file and the referencing would make it faster!

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: You really need scripting or server side compilation (such as PHP) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to the above comments. But if you need to work with plain html you may try a simple [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

If you extract your navigation in a file `navigation.html` you might simply include it in your other pages.

```
<iframe src="navigation.html"></iframe>
```

However you need to keep an eye on scripts and styles.